# What is the best effective way to get symmetric difference between two strings(in python)?

Tags: python, string, symmetric-difference

Example:
If there are two strings:-
s1 = 'cde'
s2 = 'abc'

Output: 'deab'

I converted the string into a list and compared two lists.

```
a = 'cde'
b = 'abc'
list1 = list(a)
list2 = list(b)

diff = []
for item in list1:
      if item not in list2:
            diff.append(item)
for item in list2:
      if item not in list1:
            diff.append(item)
diff = ' '.join(map(str, diff)).replace(' ','')

print(diff)
```

Is there any other way to solve this problem without converting it into the list?
I appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert each string to a `set` then use `symmetric_difference`, then finally `str.join` back into a single string

```
>>> ''.join(set(a).symmetric_difference(b))
'daeb'
```